# How do I parse rostopics from a ros bag in C++?

Tags: rosbag, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a  node that would parse a ros topic given as the input argument and display the message published by it.
Can you please give me leads to point to existing examples that I could look into?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249796/how-do-i-parse-rostopics-from-a-ros-bag-in--c++?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2016-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-11**:
I'm not sure I understand you completely, but perhaps the [topic_tools::ShapeShifter](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/topic_tools/html/classtopic__tools_1_1ShapeShifter.html) can be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand your question, you want to read a rosbag and display the messages from a particular topic? If that's the case; the [Rosbag Cookbook](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) contains a C++ example on how to do so.

The [C++ API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#cpp_api) is also helpful and contains another example on how to read from a rosbag in C++.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0